# SQL Intellisense in WPF Textbox

Tags: sql, wpf, textbox, intellisense

I am building an application which contains Textbox. I want the Textbox to act just like SQl Server Editor with intellisense. I need help, can i make my Textbox act like a Sql Server Query Editor WITH Intellisense.

Answer (score 4):

What you want cannot be easily achieved on the fly. You have to prepare the following,

- Syntax highlighting support so SQL statements can be displayed beautifully.
- SQL parser, so that you can provide auto completion suggestions.

You might start from AvalonEdit which is an excellent control that help implement syntax highlighting,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit

However, I think it is still your responsibility to write the SQL parser (as @Alexander suggested) and then integrate with AvalonEdit.

Answer (score 2):

Phil Factor worte an excellent [blog post at SimpleTalk.com](http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/08/06/1984/) on how to parse SQL using Microsoft's SQLParser with PowerShell. At the top of the post, he has included a link to Dave Ballantyne's [Cleaning Up SQL Server Deployment Scripts](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/cleaning-up-sql-server-deployment-scripts/) article, which explains how to obtain SQLParser & further work with it.

While not very specific, hopefully that will at least get you off in the right direction!

Comment: I did it, I am going to make a Codeproject.com Article ,fully explaining how to do this.

Comment: If you don't mind, please include a link to the finished article (probably best to submit & accept your own answer), so that anyone that comes across this in the future can easily find your solution.